# Is "triple" the proper counterpart of pair when describing a group of three items?

Tags: word-choice, triple-thrice

I'm writing a tech doc and this question bothers me, though I know it should be simple.

I know I should say "A pair of [Key, Value]", but when I have something like "A ____ of [Key, Value, Flag]", I'm just not sure if the proper word is *triple*, or something else.

Is *triple* often used as an adjective instead of a noun? Is there a better word?

Comment: 'Triple' can be used as an adjective: triple crown in horse racing, triple score in a video game, a triple scoop for an ice cream cone. As a noun or adjective, triple is probably the best of all the examples (the others have more context restricted usage).

Comment: another one, not mentioned yet is triplet(as a noun)

Comment: Yeah, I would say "triplet".

Comment: 'Triplet' refers most frequently to siblings born simultaneously. This is a technical document. 'Trio' is better (and shorter if you're interested in saving space).

From OED 2. A group or set of three:
b. of things or animals; in quot. 1777   a stanza of three lines; in Cricket, three runs.

Comment: Triplet is a diminutive; so the items should be so too. :)

Comment: How about a __threesome__

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you were *not* writing in a technical context, an option is the noun, [*trio*](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/trio):

> 1. [countable + singular or plural verb]
>
> a group of three people or things
>
> *A trio of English runners featured in the women's 1500 metres.*

However, for technical contexts *triple* is perfectly fine. You can use *triple* as a [noun](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/triple%5Bnoun%5D), as the Merriam Webster dictionary indicates. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/triple) indicates that one of the few uses of *triple* as a noun is:

> (mathematics, computing) A sequence of three elements or 3-tuple.

For your case, I would recommend *triple* because *trio* sounds a bit more hoity-toity. Both would be accurate, but I think *triple* carries the right tone. (For example, there are Pythagorean triples but not Pythagorean trios).

Comment: In a computing context, `3-tuple` is probably more usual. Mathematicians seem to prefer `triple`, as in your example.

Comment: Good point @Karl. Is it used in tech docs? I've only ever used it to talk about a program informally

Comment: Google NGrams doesn't seem to have heard of 3-tuples, but the use of the word 'tuple' in general has skyrocketed in the computer era (before which it was practically unheard of), so...

Comment: 'Trio' is much more restricted in usage than triple. It is the common name for a piece of music for three instruments, but is also used for a group of three people

Answer (score 8):

A couple of related words are *[threesome](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/threesome)* and *[triad](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/triad)*, both of which mean a group of three. In general, *threesome* is used for people and *triad*, for inanimate objects.

Comment: I'd use 'trio' as suggested above. 'Threesome' has sexual connotations, and 'triad' has Chinese mafia connotations. 'Trio' is nice and generic, perfect for a technical manual.

Answer (score 5):

**[triplet](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/triplet)**:

> A set or succession of three similar things.
>
> - *'The reason why a triplet or quad of Aces is worth so few points is because they can be very easy to get.'*
> - *'It constitutes a triplet, the first number representing the position, the second the wavelength and the third the transmission.'*
> - *'DNA, RNA, and protein triplets or pairs were united on the basis of a high degree of similarity as detected by the appropriate blast
>     algorithm or on the basis of annotation.'*
>
> (Oxford Dictionaries)

For some reason, nobody posted this as an answer yet even though [Theta30](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/5249/theta30) mentioned it in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39824/is-triple-the-proper-counterpart-of-pair-when-describing-a-group-of-three-item#comment72994_39824) in 2011.

Comment: Nobody posted this as an answer before you because triple is the logical increment of tuple; triplet is the logical increment of twin. In informatics, a key-value pair is called tuple or 2-tuple. Therefore, an ordered multiset of three elements such as key-value-flag would either be called 3-tuple or triple.

Answer (score 3):

In exactly your technical context, the proper term is a *"3‑tuple"*, also usable as just *"tuple"* in context. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple). The term is common among mathematicians and functional programmers, and less so in the broader techie community, but still recognizable.

An added bonus is that you can have an *"n‑tuple"*. Whenever you need one, a *5‑tuple* or an *843‑tuple* are just as fine. But then again, that *"pair of [key, value]"* is better expressed as a *"2‑tuple of [key, value]"* for the sake of consistency.

If you want a more layman-like term, I believe the good old *"trio"* would be appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I remember these. Add a supporting reference to show that this is recognised terminology.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth will [the Tuple article on good old Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) suffice?

Comment: Certainly, but it needs attributing.

Answer (score 2):

*Triple* is also used as noun, but its meaning is different from the meaning of the adjective. Among others, the meanings of *triple* as noun reported by the NOAD are the following:

- a thing that is three times as large as usual or is made up of three standard units or items
- (triples) a sporting contest in which each side has three players
- another term for trifecta

The OED reports also that *triple* as noun means "a thing consisting of three parts; a set of three items."

> He pressed […] a triple of keys.—Joyce

Answer (score 0):

In cards, after a pair you get a [prial](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/prial) for 'three of a kind'. I know it from a card game called [brag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brag_(card_game)).

Most dictionaries, and indeed the brag Wikipedia page linked above, state that it's a corruption of pair royal, but until I looked it up to make sure at least one dictionary had it, I'd never heard of a pair royal.